# Rspec: testing a rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to test that my function will properly rescue from an exception, change the parameters (filename), and try again one time. I can get the function to receive the first try, but can't get it to receive the 2nd attempt.

Controller

```
begin
  @video = get_video(video_id)
rescue
  matches = video_id.match(/(.*)[-](\d+)+x(\d+)_(\d+)/)
  swapped_dash = (matches && matches.size == 5) ? "#{matches[1]}_#{matches[2]}x#{matches[3]}_#{matches[4]}" : nil
  @video = swapped_dash.nil? ? false : get_video(swapped_dash) rescue false
end
```

Spec

```
it "attempts to find a video with an underscore if the original filename is not found" do
  controller.stub(:get_video).and_return(Exception)
  controller.should_receive(:get_video).with("MyString-480x272_8").once.ordered
  controller.should_receive(:get_video).with("MyString_480x272_8").once.ordered
  get 'player_only', :video_id => "MyString-480x272_8"
end
```

Error:

```
(#<WatchController:0x00000105d03c60>).get_video("MyString_480x272_8")
    expected: 1 time
    received: 0 times
```

Tried a few things but nothing works.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `and_raise` not `and_return`.

```
controller.stub(:get_video).and_raise(Exception)
```